# Export mongoDb collection to csv using node.js

Tags: node.js

I have mongodb collection name as country, this collection have 5 millians of people recods

I am using mongoose ORM to rean data from mongodb

I want to export all 5 millians record as csv file format when request come from angular applictaions.

Comment: You need to at least demonstrate you've attempted to solve the problm yourself

Comment: I am not sure of the latest CSV file capacities but general CSVs open in Excel which has this specification limits : https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this](https://github.com/zemirco/json2csv) module. 
You can get the JSON with mongoose and then convert it to csv with that. Then you just have to write it to a file using node `fs`.